# Dealing with context classes in Python 2.4

Tags: python, backwards-compatibility, with-statement

I'm trying to use the python-daemon module. It supplies the daemon.DaemonContext class to properly daemonize a script. Although I'm primarily targeting Python 2.6+, I'd like to maintain backwards compatibility to version 2.4.

Python 2.5 supports importing contexts from **future**, but Python 2.4 has no such facility.
I figured I could just catch whatever error the with statement raises and enter and exit the context manually for 2.4, but I can't seem to catch the SyntaxError raised.

Is there any way to accomplish this short of explicitly checking the interpreter version?
Below is the gist of what I'm trying to do and the problem I'm getting. In Real Life I don't have control of the context class, so it needs to work without mangling the original class, ie not like [these ideas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547526/improvizing-a-drop-in-replacement-for-the-with-statement-for-python-2-4)

Nevermind if Python 2.4 can't run python-daemon; I'd at least like to able to catch the error and implement a fallback or something.

Thanks for helping.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
from __future__ import with_statement
# with_statement isn't in __future__ in 2.4.
# In interactive mode this raises a SyntaxError.
# During normal execution it doesn't, but I wouldn't be able to catch it
# anyways because __future__ imports must be at the beginning of the file, so
# that point is moot.


class contextable(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print('Entering context.')
        return None
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print('Exiting context.')
        return False

def spam():
    print('Within context.')

context = contextable()

try:
    with context: # This raises an uncatchable SyntaxError.
        spam()
except SyntaxError, e: # This is how I would like to work around it.
    context.__enter__()
    try:
        spam()
    finally:
        context.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SyntaxError` is diagnosed by the Python compiler as it compiles -- you're presumably trying to "catch" it from code that's being compiled as part of the same module (e.g., that's what you're doing in your code sample), so of course it won't work -- your "catching" code hasn't been compiled yet (because compilation has terminated unsuccessfully) so it can't catch anything.

You need to ensure the code that might have a syntax error gets compiled *later* than the catching code -- either put it in a separate module that you import in the `try` clause, or in a string you `compile` with the built-in by that name (you can later execute the bytecode resulting from the `compile` call, if it terminates successfully).

Neither possibility looks good for your purposes, I think.  I suspect that using two separate modules (and probably picking between them depending on the "does this compile" check, but a version check sounds much cleaner to me) is the only "clean" solution, unfortunately.

**Edit**: here's how to microbenchmark try/except against version checks:

```
$ python2.4 -mtimeit 'try:
  compile("with x: pass", "", "exec")
except SyntaxError: x=1
else: x=2'
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.8 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit 'try:
  compile("with x: pass", "", "exec")
except SyntaxError: x=1
else: x=2'
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.5 usec per loop

$ python2.4 -mtimeit -s'import sys' 'if sys.version>="2.5": x=2
else: x=1'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.221 usec per loop
$ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'import sys' 'if sys.version>="2.5": x=2
else: x=1'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.156 usec per loop
```

As you see, the version I consider cleaner is `10.8 / 0.221`, almost 50 times faster, on 2.4, and `40.5 / 0.156`, almost 260 times faster, on 2.6.  In general (with rare exceptions), the clean (i.e., "pythonic") approach will turn out to be the better optimized one in Python -- often, at least part of the reason can be that Python core developers focus on facilitating and encouraging the use of constructs they like, rather than that of constructs they dislike.

Comment: I was afraid of this. As you said, conditionally compiling a string sounds fairly messy for no good reason, so that's out. So I'll pick between modules while keeping them as small as possible.

As for how to differentiate, catching the error and checking the version are approximately equally "clean," so which is faster - comparing sys.version_info every time or eating an exception sometimes? It's probably negligible but I'd like an opinion.

Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @hippie, to micro-benchmark things, never guess, always _measure_.  `timeit` is your friend.  Editing my A to supply an example.

Comment: Of course that version check is faster than compilation. To do anything with the comparison test, it will need to import (compile) code, not just make two assignments. For Python 2.5, the exception check is actually slightly faster (3.47s vs 3.87s on my machine with 1,000,000 iterations through timeit). However on 2.4, the exception check is approximately 30 times slower due to catching the SyntaxError every time. The version check is obviously better, but your example doesn't show the real reason why. =)