# Can you use python-daemon with Python 2.4?

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I'm converting my program to run as a daemon on Linux.  I'd like to use the [python-daemon package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) to save repeating the work.  However, I need to support python 2.4.

The example given on the page uses the `with` keyword so implies python 2.5; [context managers](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) are also listed as being supported from 2.5.

Can I just call the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods myself instead?  Or is there more to it than that?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518472/dealing-with-context-classes-in-python-2-4) *nearly* answers my question, but just misses it at the last minute.

Comment: If you can have another daemon, then [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) would bypass your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the source code, it should be easily possible to use python-daemon in Python 2.4.  (I don't have a Python 2.4 installation around to actually try, though.)  The `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods of `DaemonContext` are essentially aliases for `open()` and `close()`, so the equivalent of

```
with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program()
```

would simply be

```
context = daemon.DaemonContext()
context.open()
try:
    do_main_program()
finally:
    context.close()
```

I couldn't find anything Python 2.5 specific while skimming through all of the source code.  (There are a few Python 2.4 specific constructs, though, like a few decorators and `reversed()`, so it won't work with Python 2.3 out of the box.)

Comment: That's what I wanted to know.  Thanks!

Comment: @wilbo: So it actually did work with Python 2.4?  (Just to make sure future visitors of this page will actually find the answer to the question.)

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  I'll comment here again if I do come across any problems.